# Yii2: How to customize reset password form (view)

Tags: php, yii2, backend

I'm trying to found the reset password view in my Yii2 project to add a recaptcha at the bottom but I can't find it anywhere... I did some deeper google researching and I found nothing... Seems like yii community is very small.

Comment: which User  component you are using ...  should vbe declare in your config files  (main.php or main-local  ..)

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate. Do you have a button on the login that takes you to a separate page for re-setting the password and you are just trying to add something to it, or do you not have a reset password page that you can access?

If you do, the URL would likely end in something like this -

```
index.php?r=site%2Fforgot
```

If this is the case, then you have an action function inside your SiteController called "actionForgot". At the bottom of the function you will find the render call. Inside the render call you will see the name of the view being rendered by the action.

In most cases, its called something similar to the name of the action for convenience sake. So you will likely find the view at "/views/site/" with the name forgot.php or something similar.

If you do not have a reset password section at all, its because you do not have a view or controller action for this.